# Is there a significant difference in results between working with QGIS vs. SNAP?

Tags: qgis, sentinel-snap

I need to work with Sentinel-2 data, and I have been having difficult with the ESA toolbox (SNAP), so I've decided to process the imagery with QGIS instead.

My question is, is there a significant difference in the quality of atmospherical correction results that would justify working with SNAP instead of QGIS?

Comment: .SAFE format is to organize the information. I don't understand what you want... If is correct atmospherically the scenes, .jp2 will be useless for Sen2cor outside SNAP

Comment: I want to correct the scenes outside of SNAP (so, that is, not on Sen2Cor).

But I just realized I made a mistake and thought .SAFE was also a specific image format. My bad, I will change edit the question again.

Comment: Also, you are wrong about Sen2Cor... Read carefully http://step.esa.int/main/third-party-plugins-2/sen2cor/

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand your comment. I am wrong about what regarding Sen2Cor?

Comment: Sen2cor is an add-in to SNAP... I've never use it inside SNAP, always from cmd/terminal. Try from command line. SNAP take account water vapor, cirrus, aerosols and others variables (such land use - computed from sen2cor-, snow, water bodies, DEM)... So the performance of this tool is better than QGIS DOS or i.atcorr

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you. I am afraid my English is not very good, or at least it doesn't pass muster when it comes to technical vocabulary.

Thank you, again, for your reply.